# Installing Erlang to use Phoenix and Erlang packages "not installable" on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have elixir working and I am trying to run a phoenix server.

Everything works fine until I need to run the server doing mix phx.server and I get this error:

```
Compiling 1 file (.yrl)
/usr/lib/erlang/lib/parsetools-2.1.8/include/yeccpre.hrl: no such file or directory
could not compile dependency :gettext, "mix compile" failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile gettext", update it with "mix deps.update gettext" or clean it with "mix deps.clean gettext"
```

Installing parsetools just gives me more errors.

If I try to install Erlang doing this:

```
sudo apt install esl-erlang
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 esl-erlang : Depends: libncurses5 but it is not installable
              Depends: libwxbase2.8-0 but it is not installable or
                       libwxbase3.0-0 but it is not installable or
                       libwxbase3.0-0v5 but it is not installable
              Depends: libwxgtk2.8-0 but it is not installable or
                       libwxgtk3.0-0 but it is not installable or
                       libwxgtk3.0-0v5 but it is not installable or
                       libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0v5 but it is not installable
              Depends: libsctp1 but it is not installable
              Recommends: erlang-mode but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't know where to go at that point.

Comment: Do you have docker in your Ubuntu? If yes I can show you the Docker way, that's the way I run everything for development in my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The painless way to install *OTP* on [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) machines would be to use packages provided by [*Erlang Solutions*](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html).

Remove everything installed in `apt search erlang` and follow the instructions on the page I linked under “Installation using repository.”

Comment: When I try to remove any of the items that appear in the search, it says they are not found. If I try and do another search, all the same items appear (including the ones I just tried to remove)

Comment: When I do the update command I get this:  https://imgur.com/0DnAzLW

Comment: When I do apt search erlang I get all this stuff: https://jsfiddle.net/3vqak2np/    but I can't tell if any of it is installed. When I try to delete it says they don't exist

Comment: OK, try to simply use installations instructions I linked. _Erlang Solutions_ packages, in theory, should take care of removing legacy ones.

Comment: It doesn't work. It won't install at all now that way

Comment: _“It won't install at all now that way”_ it is impossible to create the package in _Debian-like distro_ that the user cannot enforce to install. Since you did not bother to even publish the error you receive back, I consider I cannot be of any help here anymore.

Comment: It's the same one I posted  above. The error is just going in circles. It's the same errors in the original post

Comment: What is says when you try to `sudo apt remove esl-erlang`?

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'esl-erlang' is not installed, so not removed
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  gconf2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Pop!_OS 18.10
Release: 18.10
Codename: cosmic

Comment: When I do "sudo apt-get update" I get this:   sudo apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/